# How can I combine functions from an interface with types?

Tags: typescript

For a school project I'm supposed to make a type-safe LINQ in typescript using advanced types.

I'm struggling to find a way to have all my tables(types) use the same interface.

I want the functions to be able to string together something like this:

```
students.Select("Name", "Surname").Include("Grades", q =>
  q.Select("Grade", "CourseId" )
)
```

So I started with a type `student` and created a table `students` with some values:

```
type Student = {
    Name: string,
    Surname: string
}

let students: Student[] = [
    {Name: "Foo", Surname: "Bar"},
    {Name: "John", Surname: "Wick"}
]
```

And wanted to combine it with an interface so that I don't have to rewrite the `select` multiple times.

```
interface Entity<T> {
    Select: (args: T[]) => T
}
```

Trying to combine it through `type Student = Entity<T> & {` doesn't seem to work because then I would need to add the generic type `T` to the students table and create `select` per type.

How can I make it so that the table `students` is able to use the functions from `Entity<T>` and chain them like shown in the first example? Or am I approaching this problem wrong and should I try a different angle?

I can give more information if necessary but didn't want to make it too lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript, it's possible to add methods to the Array object as you're trying to do, but it's generally considered a bad idea (Imagine if you were using a library that tried to add a method with the same name to the global Array object!)

I would suggest making a new Array type that extends the basic Array type. e.g.

```
class LinqArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    Select(...args: T[]): LinqArray<T> {
        // Implementation
    }
}

let students: LinqArray<Student> = new LinqArray();
students.push({Name: "Foo", Surname: "Bar"});
students.push({Name: "John", Surname: "Wick"});

// Works
students.Select("prop");
```